# Remove an association in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a Post model associated with User model like so:

```
likes: [{
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'user'
}]
```

I want to remove the first like in the post:

```
post.likes[0].remove();
post.save();
```

This removes not only the like but also the user. How can I remove the like but keep the user? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the operator [$pop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/)

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate( 
      {
         post: idPost,
      },
      { 
         $pop: {
           likes : -1, 
         },
      }
 ).then(...).catch(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I eventually used $pull. And used the post model object for the update operation. But yes, the answer is to use update and not save :)